# Is there a possibility to run applets on Android or Blackberry?

Tags: java, android, blackberry, applet

This is what the Java site [www.java.com](http://www.java.com) says:

"KVM, the virtual machine for mobile devices, is the counterpart of JVM (Java virtual machine). It is used to run applets and applications written with Java technology on mobile devices. KVM must be installed by the manufacturer. It is NOT available for download or installation by consumers".

Now Android has a customized virtual machine called DVM (Dalvik Virtual Machine). Can we compare it with KVM? Wonder if we can further reprogram DVM to incorporate features of KVM to run applets on Android?
Same goes for Blacberry, is there a possibility?

Comment: Java applets are dead? Far from it. They offer a couple of advantages for content producers. First, they are binaries; you cannot just look at (and fiddle with) the source like you can with javascript. Secondly, the lack of support for java applets in the mobile browsers pushes people to buy the corresponding native app. I.e. only offering a java applet on the website drives sales of the native app!

Answer (score 5):

Jave applet is still alive, many organizations use it, a lot of HMI's use it,also banks,
I wanted to buy few android tablets and use it in our factory for our technicians,
But no applet support, so i will go on use my android tablet as game machine for my children.

Answer (score 3):

> Wonder if we can further reprogram DVM
>   to incorporate features of KVM to run
>   applets on Android?

There is very little overlap between what Android provides and what an applet needs, such as AWT. Since applets, as a technology, have been dead for over a decade, I cannot imagine that it would be worth anyone's effort to modify the Android firmware to include the necessary classes and figure out how to run an applet in an Android activity.

Comment: Thanks Mark!i can appreciate what you meant. But even today there are so many games and animations still on applets.Programmers have to take  advantage of either OpenGL and/or Graphics libraries when they want to program such games or like to some serious animation or simulation. Once we have applets running on Android we can have those programs running on mobiles. Please do correct or criticize me where i am wrong or not justified.
Thanks again.

Comment: I think it is a big, very big Android failure! My Samsung Galaxy Tab , a U$ 990 device, is next to useless as a mobile alternative to access ALL Internet Banking in Brazil because security is ubiquitously implemented via java applets at the login screen. I've opted for a Galaxy instead of the iPad because I was 100% sure it would support Java and applets and I just threw my money away: no internet banking, no home broker, nothing that requires Java... Epic android fail IMHO, but still in many places way better than apple anyway...

Answer (score 3):

Applets are not supported on the phones by default. Customers can buy a browser which supports it such as the Cloud browser. We have a technology to convert existing Java applets to allow them to run on mobile devices without a special browser. If your company is in need of this service please contact us through our unitedswe website.

Answer (score 2):

Applets will NOT run on the BlackBerry for various reasons, most importantly that the AWT classes applets depend on are not available on the BlackBerry. The UI model is very different, consisting of either the MIDP UI model or the BlackBerry model, neither of which is AWT.

Going forward, you should be using JavaScript for browser-side computing, it's the only thing that will work crossbrowser on mobile platforms. Applets are very much dead technology, unfortunately.

Comment: Dead as in not supported? They obviously aren't dead in usage.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen applications running cdlc/mid profile on android, as Android underlying is a Linux kernel anyway, after you root your device, I don't see there's difficulties installing another JVM under linux, which in turns support CDC profiles.

But the problem is will it integrate the default browser well? Will 2x JVM (Dalvik/ OpenJava lets say) make the memory management alot more complecated?

Comment: I have a rooted phone.. Tell me how to install a custom.jvm

Answer (score 1):

Oracle is offering something called [Application Development Framework Mobile](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf-mobile/overview/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen). If I understand the page correctly, this framework helps to create java applications for ios and android. 
You would have to abandon the applet idea, though, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I can execute Java applets on my S2 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTE & firefox browser with my rooted samsung stock android phone (4.1.2).

Install linux for Android, configure your Linux distro to run oracle/sun Java applets and Voila!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, rooting your Android device and then loading Linux and then installing Java to that OS works just fine.
Here's a guide you may use and modify that I compiled for a different ~.jar file I wanted to run

http://forums.rptools.net/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=24082&sid=3092b606dd5c7278e0908f021956b9f3

Best part was once I got port forwarding figured out for my network I was able to host a public server from within this little environment.

Hope this helps you all because I've tested this with other Java dependent software and the ARMel and ARMhf versions of Java's JDK work great.

#
Edit/Update
#
http://www.timelesssky.com/blog/running-debian-armhf-alongside-android
After following the above link's instructions I was able to run-
    apt-caxh search java
-And Orical's Java JDK was available to install though the package manager when running Wheezy Hard Float on Android with Debian Kit app.
Next step is to see if Kali will install via the shroot method offered by this app's modded code.