# Run applet in Android tablet

Tags: java, android, applet, tablet

I have already some applets ready. 
I tried to run it on android tablet.
Will it not work at all?
I am not sure?
Do any one knows this?

Or is it like after android. Java is not platform independent -  ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a possibility to run applets on Android or Blackberry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433338/is-there-a-possibility-to-run-applets-on-android-or-blackberry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there is no JRE (Java Runtime Environment) for Android so there is no way of running applets. For more detailed information, see the following page: http://www.technipages.com/can-java-applets-run-on-android.html

Here is an interesting article about someone porting a Java Applet to Android: [An Adventure in Porting a Java Applet to Android with no Previous Experience with Android](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/269318/An-Adventure-in-Porting-a-Java-Applet-to-Android-w)

Comment: So, java is not platform independent now?? :)

Comment: This can be seen as: web-browsers are usually C++ based, why don't they handle C++ apps. Also see updated answer for more information.

Comment: @Software Guruji, "java platform independence" is a myth however that has nothing to do with your issue. It's not the language that's mythed to be platform independent, it's the environment (the Java Virtual Machine); the language is simply a tool to develop code for the JVM. Your problem with Android though is there is no JVM... Android primarily uses the same Java language, but the back end is not providing a compatible (or even close) execution environment. You're fortunate that bytecode is in the build path, but for a JVM it's the destination, and just an intermediate step for Android.

Comment: @mah what I mean was, There is a myth "java is platform independent" and wherever we install JVM (if it exist) then we can run .class file or an applet on that machine. But here there is NO jvm for android so I was sarcasm for that myth... `Java a platform independent` as I learnt it when I started my study for Java... :)

Comment: @Software Guruji Please accept if it answers your initial question.

Comment: as @Software Guruji stated, JVM is a myth, oracle faced the ugly truth.

Answer (score 2):

> Java is not platform independent..

Java SE is intended for desktop and laptop use, and together with Java EE, servers.

An Applet would not work (even) in the runtime intended for phones - Java ME.  There are GUI elements in desktop apps. & applets that are *unusable on a small screen.*  Even if they were, many dialogs and other elements would not have the 'look and feel' of the native phone equivalents (even using PLAFs).

Answer (score 0):

It wont run because the api for running applets is not writen on the android jvm. There was or is a legal battle between google and oracle involving Java(tm) and I think that's the main reason this api is not implemented neither by 3rd parties neither by google.